# How do I solve a React memory leak involving FiberNode and performWorkUntilDeadline

Tags: html, reactjs

My React based web page seems to leak. There are no error messages or warnings, but the memory seems to be constantly increasing every time the UI is modified. There doesn't seem to be any retained detached  DOM elements. Looking at the retained objects, nothing there seems to be coming from any of the code I wrote. Instead, I see a vast number of FiberNode. By making use of the Edge dev tools, I can see that they're mostly retained by performWorkUntilDeadline functions held directly by the root. I am certainly not calling performWorkUntilDeadline directly.

I've tried to see if any components were mounted too many times, but that didn't seem to be the case. Every component is mounted at most once more than it's unmounted. I tried finding similar issues, but nothing showed up as being particularly relevant. I've tried waiting a while, in case it's only a time issue, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I've tried to isolate some interaction, but all UI interactions seem to reproduce the issue.

For example, the following code will reproduce the issue simply by resizing the drawer.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { Transitions } from '@mui/material';
import { Drawer } from '@mui/material';
import { MUIStyledCommonProps } from '@mui/system';

export const shouldUseDevStreams = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development';

export default function App() {
  const minDrawerWidth = 258;
  const maxDrawerWidth = 2000;
  const defaultDrawerWidth = 258;

  const [leftDrawerWidth, setLeftDrawerWidth] = React.useState(defaultDrawerWidth);

  const Main = styled('main', {
    shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'leftOpen'
  })(({ theme }: MUIStyledCommonProps) => ({
    flexGrow: 1,
    ...{
      transition: (theme?.transitions as Transitions).create('margin', {
        easing: (theme?.transitions as Transitions).easing.easeOut,
        duration: (theme?.transitions as Transitions).duration.enteringScreen
      }),
      marginLeft: `${leftDrawerWidth}px`
    }
  }));

  const handleLeftDrawerMouseDown = () => {
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleLeftDrawerMouseUp, true);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleLeftDrawerMouseMove, true);
  };

  const handleLeftDrawerMouseUp = () => {
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleLeftDrawerMouseUp, true);
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleLeftDrawerMouseMove, true);
  };

  const handleLeftDrawerMouseMove = (e: { clientX: number }) => {
    const newWidth = e.clientX - document.body.offsetLeft + 2;

    const maxWidth = Math.min(maxDrawerWidth, document.body.offsetWidth);

    if (newWidth > minDrawerWidth && newWidth < maxWidth) {
      setLeftDrawerWidth(newWidth);
    }
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Drawer
        data-testid="leftDrawer"
        variant="persistent"
        anchor="left"
        open={true}
        sx={{
          width: leftDrawerWidth,
          flexShrink: 0,
          '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
            width: leftDrawerWidth,
            boxSizing: 'border-box'
          }
        }}
        PaperProps={{
          variant: 'outlined'
        }}>
        <div onMouseDown={() => handleLeftDrawerMouseDown()} className="left-dragger" />
      </Drawer>

      <Main></Main>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```